# Why do I need to store generator function to a variable first?

Tags: python, generator, yield

I am exploring the use of generators in python, but I'm running into a strange kind of issue.

How can it be that the following code works as expected (e.g. returns next fibonacci number every time function is called):

```
def fibonacci():                                       
    current, previous = 0,1                             
    while True:                                         
        yield current
        current, previous = current + previous, current

fib = fibonacci()

for i in range(0,21):
    print(next(fib))
```

But when I directly call the function inside my for-loop, as such:

```
for i in range(0,21):
    print(next(fibonacci()))
```

It prints out 21 zero's?

Comment: Because then you are making new `generator` object in every iteration, getting first element over and over.

Comment: Thanks, I see. I didn't know the fist call to fibonacci() was initializing the generator object. Wonder why this question got so much negative response, since it's not that obvious to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Chris said in his comment:

> Because then you are making new generator object in every iteration, getting first element over and over.

You *can* avoid assigning it to a variable by iterating over it directly. This way you create only a single generator object:

```
for n, i in zip(fibonacci(), range(0,21)):
    print(n)
```

Comment: A better solution would be to add the range parameter to `fibonacci` itself and use `enumerate`

Comment: @L3viathan True. The function should technically control the number of iterations to avoid such a casualty.